# sales_flat_shipment, created_at is stored with difference of 4 hours

Tags: shipment, date

I have this problem when I ship my order.
the date field created_at is stored with difference of 4 hours.
it's the same problem with sales_flat_shipment_track.
ex: I shipped today at 11:56AM, but in my db, I have 2015-10-07 15:56:22

Do you have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're located on the east coast and currently on Eastern Time, which is 4 hours earlier than UTC/GMT. Magento saves all of its timestamps in standard UTC/GMT time, so you can display times adjusted to your locale correctly.

Note this only applies to native Magento modules. If you have custom extension, you have to adjust the times yourself for saving and displaying.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for this explanation

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the answer if it was.